# Patching java classes in another project with a child class without modifying the source code

Tags: java, gradle

## Goal

I have a project A whose source I do not want to modify. I want to "merge" it with a project B on build such that:

1. Classes in B replace classes in A.
2. Any classes that are replaced in A are moved s.t. the classes in B can keep inherit from those classes.

The purpose of this is to be able to "hijack" behaviours in project A by wrapping methods (and in some instanced replacing them all together) without having to do so in the project A source code.

## Example

Given a class `Foo` in project A under the namspace `org.bar`, we have a class

```
public class Foo extends org.bar.Foo {
    @Override
    public void doThings() {
        // doOtherThings
        super.doThings();
        // doEvenMoreThings
    }
}
```

in project B that will be called instead of the original `Foo` class by other code in project A.

## My problem / what I tried

My idea for solving this was to create a shadowed jar of project A s.t. all classes except those to be patched would move to a new namespace matching the namespace of project B and then merge the two. However, I was unable to patch the references to those classes within project A.

The problem I have is replacing any namespace reference to the original classes to the patched classes while keeping the reference "parent" reference in the patched classes. Any attempt to do so has resulted in java complaining, at runtime, that the references are borked (this was a few months ago and I do not have the errorlogs).

Comment: If Project A was not designed for extension/wrapping/decorating/injection, then why use it?  This sounds like a really, really bad idea.

Comment: @AndrewS It's a custom client for a very old video game to add QOL features. The problem is that the devs have very strange views on how to write and format their code which makes it a headache to maintain re: merge conflicts. There are also other design choices which make active modification of the original source a pain. I would not want to do this in production.

Comment: Was thinking you could do it with an intermediate jar which simply moved `foo.bar` to `shaded.foo.bar` and then re-implement them all in your extension class, but that wouldn't intercept calls between classes in the original `foo.bar`...  Another possible option would be some kind of aspect oriented programming, but with the requirements to have both classpath collisions PLUS extension, I'm not sure how you could get there natively.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a case for **AOP, Aspect Oriented Programming**. It can intercept calls and provide one's own filtering.

It is both a tricky patching instead of just rewriting code.
But you can return in the old code your child class instance when originally their base class instance was returned.

[Baeldung on Spring's AOP](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop)

Whether this is a feasible approach depends.